# Could not find header file for OPENSSL

Tags: http, lua, openssl, luarocks, luasec

I am trying to install Luasec on Ubuntu terminal, but it just keeps displaying this error to me:

```
Error: Could not find header file for OPENSSL
   No file openssl/ssl.h in /usr/local/include
   No file openssl.h/ssl.h/ in /usr/include
   No file openssl/ssl.h in /include
You may have to install OPENSSL in your system and/or pass OPENSSL_DIR or OPENSSL_INCDIR to the luarocks command.
```

When I check OpenSSL version it says its 1.1.1f

[image]

So how do I proceed?

Comment: which operating system?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Fixed the issue by Installing OpenSSL with terminal through Luarocks with the command:

```
Luarocks install openssl
```

And now after installing it, it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer isn't unclear, it's plain wrong. First of all the `luarocks` command should probably be using a lowercase `l`. **Second, there is no `openssl` package on Luarocks.** Third, SSL-related packages on Luarocks (such as `luaossl`) appear to just be bindings to `openssl`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt -y install libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any of the mentioned answers solves the problem. Hence sharing what worked for me.

OS: macOS Ventura

Before running this command, I had [lua](https://www.lua.org/start.html) and openssl (`brew install openssl`) installed.

What you need to figure out is the path for these two. Start looking them inside `/usr/local/Cellular` folder and update in below format:

```
luarocks --lua-dir /usr/local/Cellar/lua/5.4.4_1/ install luasec OPENSSL_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1t
```

This way we are explicitly telling the command where the required directory are.

Answer (score -1):

Despite the lowercase `l` this solution works for me (independent of what some responders told here)

`luarocks install openssl`