# Luarocks openssl

Tags: lua, openssl, luarocks

I am trying to install luajwt using the following command:

```
$ sudo luarocks install --server=http://rocks.moonscript.org luajwt
```

But unfortunately, I receive the following error:

```
Installing http://rocks.moonscript.org/luajwt-1.3-4.src.rock
Missing dependencies for luajwt 1.3-4:
   luacrypto >= 0.3.2-1 (not installed)
   lua-cjson >= 2.1.0 (not installed)
   lbase64 >= 20120807-3 (not installed)

luajwt 1.3-4 depends on lua >= 5.1 (5.4-1 provided by VM)
luajwt 1.3-4 depends on luacrypto >= 0.3.2-1 (not installed)
Installing http://rocks.moonscript.org/luacrypto-0.3.2-2.src.rock

Error: Failed installing dependency: http://rocks.moonscript.org/luacrypto-0.3.2-2.src.rock - Could not find header file for OPENSSL
  No file openssl/evp.h in /usr/local/include
  No file openssl/evp.h in /usr/include
  No file openssl/evp.h in /include
  No file openssl/evp.h in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
  No file openssl/evp.h in /usr/local/opt/include
You may have to install OPENSSL in your system and/or pass OPENSSL_DIR or OPENSSL_INCDIR to the luarocks command.
Example: luarocks install luacrypto OPENSSL_DIR=/usr/local
```

I tried to resolve that issue by installing OpenSSL with luarocks but I am getting the same error:

```
➜ Luarocks install openssl

Installing https://luarocks.org/openssl-0.8.2-1.src.rock

Error: Could not find header file for OPENSSL
  No file openssl/evp.h in /usr/local/include
  No file openssl/evp.h in /usr/include
  No file openssl/evp.h in /include
  No file openssl/evp.h in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
  No file openssl/evp.h in /usr/local/opt/include
You may have to install OPENSSL in your system and/or pass OPENSSL_DIR or OPENSSL_INCDIR to the luarocks command.
Example: luarocks install openssl OPENSSL_DIR=/usr/local
```

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: You can't install OpenSSL using Luarocks, you'll have to install it using your system's package manager.

Comment: Here it says I can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71734476/could-not-find-header-file-for-openssl

Comment: That doesn't mean you can. There is no `openssl` package on Luarocks. `luaossl` is just a binding to `openssl`.

Comment: @NivHamisha install `libssl-dev` in your system.